# PAGE Specific Email Notifications

Tags: email, notifications

Is there a plugin, or a way that I can set a PAGE that has comments enabled to send an email notification to my subscribers?

I don't want to enable email notification for all my pages that allow comments, but just certain pages.

By activating email notification for a specific page, whenever I post a comment on that page I would like all my subscribers to receive a notification that includes the actual text of the comment.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this issue is I would first find a comment notification plugin that works well and has been recently updated.  This one seems to fit the bill just fine:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/installation/

Then I would come up with some way of marking the pages that I want comment notifications on.  You could do this with a custom metabox (http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) or even with a category or specific tag.

Finally you need a way to allow the comment subscription to only work on pages that meet your criteria.  The plugin I linked above gave this wonderful hint:

> Optional: if your WordPress theme doesn't have the comment_form hook, or if you would like >to manually determine where in your comments form the subscribe checkbox appears, enter >this where you would like it:

So, it would be pretty trivial to figure out the function that shows the checkbox or (even better) by examining the plugin - to figure out what filters and actions it uses, and simply remove them using remove_action() and remove_filter() - for any post that doesn't meet the subscription criteria.

I would probably use a filter for 'after_setup_theme' since that fires after 'plugins_loaded'.